# Can't install giplet on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation, software-installation

I cannot install giplet. Are there any alternative ways to showing my IP address on the Ubuntu panel?

```
sekai92@sekai92-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install giplet
password for sekai92: 
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
 E: Unable to locate package giplet 
sekai92@sekai92-VirtualBox:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

[Giplet is not available since Oneiric](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/giplet/+publishinghistory). It was removed from Ubuntu and Debian since it doesn't work under Gnome 3.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=645486

> Package: ftp.debian.org
>   Severity: normal
>
> Hi,
>
> please remove giplet package from the archive, 
>   It does not work anymore with GNOME3
>
> Thanks in advance,
>
> Fabrizio

There isn't any known alternative.